# Por que só consigo manipular arquivos com ponteiro?

Tags: c, arquivo, ponteiro

Na declaração sempre tenho que colocar

```
FILE *Arq;
```

Se coloco sem o * ele apresenta um erro.
Qual o motivo?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Porque o dado que a função `fopen()` retorna é um ponteiro, então tem que declarar a variável com um tipo compatível. Se ela retornasse outra coisa seria isto que você tem que declarar na variável que ira sustentar o objeto que cuidará da manipulação do arquivo. Veja a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).

Poderia questionar o motivo dele retornar ponteiro. Ele é um objeto complexo e que tem informações em uma área fora da [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), até mesmo gerenciado pelo sistema operacional, então acessar [indiretamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) é a única opção.